# How to connect with redis sever in python while having a Key Error?

Tags: python

I'm trying to set up my first Docker Container. For this I wrote an app where you can choose between 3 options and vote for your prefered. However I get a Key Error telling me, that I haven't defined my variable 'REDIS' to connect to the Redis server. How do I connect with it?

I don't know where or how to link it in my code. And whatever I try I get back that error. Here the important code:

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template
import os
import random
import redis
import socket
import sys

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config.from_pyfile('config_file.cfg')

if("VOTE1VALUE" in os.environ and os.environ['VOTE1VALUE']):
        button1 = os.environ['VOTE1VALUE']
else:
        button1 = app.config['VOTE1VALUE']

if("VOTE2VALUE" in os.environ and os.environ['VOTE2VALUE']):
        button2 = os.environ['VOTE2VALUE']
else:
        button2 = app.config['VOTE2VALUE']

if("VOTE3VALUE" in os.environ and os.environ['VOTE3VALUE']):
        button2 = os.environ['VOTE3VALUE']
else:
        button2 = app.config['VOTE3VALUE']

if("TITLE" in os.environ and os.environ['TITLE']):
        title = os.environ['TITLE']
else:
        title = app.config['TITLE']

redis_server = os.environ['REDIS']

try:
        if "REDIS_PWD" in os.environ:
            r = redis.StrictRedis(host=redis_server,
                    port = 6379,
                    password = os.environ['REDIS_PWD'])
        else:
            r = redis.Redis(redis_server)
        r.ping()
except redis.ConnectionError:
        exit('Failed to connect to Redis, terminating.')
```

I thought I'd get it to work like this but when I try to run the docker image I get following Error:

```
File "programm.py", line 32, in <module>
 redis_server = os.environ['REDIS']
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/os.py", line 669, in __getitem__
 raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'REDIS'
```

My question is how to get it to work? And how to connect my programm to the Redis Server.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Your code fails as there is no environment variable 'REDIS'.
Depending on what you can edit and how you are running your container, you might:

1. Declare the REDIS ENV variable in the Dockerfile
2. Extend the Docker image just to add your REDIS ENV variable. Then use the new image
3. Specify the environment variable value with the `docker run` option "`-e`"
4. In case of Docker compose, you can specify the environment variable in the Docker compose file. In this case you might also include Redis as a Docker image, thus it would all be self-contained. Beware of modules though

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! How do I declare the REDIS ENV in my Dockerfile?

Comment: From Docker manual:
`ENV <key> <value>` or `ENV <key>=<value> ...`

Remember to rebuild the image though.

Comment: Ok thank you, but I mean I set ENV REDIS <value> and what is the value?

Comment: Based on the code you attached, it should contain the Redis hostname.

Comment: I'm very sorry for being so stupid but can you give the explicit example? I don't get how to do it ...

Comment: Example of what? Of a Redis Host? That's just a hostname, e.g. `10.0.0.1` or `redis.foester.com`.

Comment: Oh ok! Thanks. Can I just set one or?

Comment: Unless you are using multiple Redis hosts in a cluster, or multiple independent Redis, you have to just specify 1 single hostname.

Comment: Now it is telling me that it failed to connect to Redis and is terminating. You know why?

Comment: It may be because the hostname is not correct or your Redis instance is not up-and-running or your Redis instance is not running in port 6379. Depending on your network, it could be also a matter of firewalls.

Comment: What is your Redis host?

Comment: Any tips for finding out what it is? I don't think it is the hostname...in my programm I don't use it, all is declared with redis_server and I declared port 6379.

Comment: I called my hostname 'Host' (not very creative :D)

Comment: You cannot simply invent your Redis hostname. Someone should provide it to you. Are you in a LAN/WAN? Or everything is running in your computer?

Comment: Everything is running in my computer

Comment: That's great. Since you are using your own computer, one thing you might do is use a docker-compose file that contains both your app and the Redis instance. This way you can define an arbitrary name for that container and refer it.